# Integral of Bessel function of 1st kind with complex exponential

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, special-functions, integration

Does someone know the solution (simple closed form) of one of theses integrals:
$$\int_0^t J_l(s) e^{-iA(t-s)}ds$$
$$\int_0^t \frac{J_l(s)}{s}  e^{-iA(t-s)}ds$$
with $l>0$, $t>0$, $\Re(A)>0$, $\Im(A)<0$.

Thank you very much.

Comment: ? solution ? I don't see much reason to hope for some simple closed form expression.

Comment: Can you do this special case? $$\int _{0}^{t}\!{{\rm J}_1(s)}{{\rm e}^{-2\,i ( t-s
) }}{ds} $$